# TYPO3 data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, web-services, json, typo3

I need to create a project that uses TYPO3 and an iPhone app. I am not familiar with TYPO3 so I need your help.

Is there a plugin that can give data via XML or JSON from the TYPO3 backend? I just need the data, e.g.' home page text and images for me to show on an iPhone application or images for gallery on an iPhone app.

Your comments and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi. have you found anything useful?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension, which uses xmlrpc to retrieve the data from your typo3 installation, but you could adapt it to json, if you would like :
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/typo3_webservice/current/
Read the extension manual, there is an example of iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

exporting json, XML or any other kind of feed is quite easy. There are different ways to do this.

- Use Typoscript to query the database (see CONTENT cObject) and fill a Template (see TEMPLATE cObject)
- Create an extension and implement the data export as PHP script
- Use tt_news' RSS and Atom export to generate standard compliant Newsfeeds

In any case you have to find out what kind of data is expected by the iPhone app.

There may also be a data exporter extensions ready to use in the Typo3 Extension repo. Check it out. I for my part would go with the first way using TypoScript for the export, maybe wrapped within an extension.

Good luck.

cu
Roman